# Disable checkbox and keep it disabled using cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, checkbox

This will keep the checkbox checked:

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, expiredays) {
  var exdate = new Date()
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays)
  document.cookie = c_name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate)
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=")
    if (c_start != -1) {
      c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1
      c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start)
      if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end))
    }
  }
  return null
}
onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('myCheck').checked = getCookie('myCheck') == 1 ? true : false;
}

function set_check() {
  setCookie('myCheck', document.getElementById('myCheck').checked ? 1 : 0, 100);
}
```

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="myCheck" onclick="set_check();">
```

I would also like to disable the checkbox after it's checked and keep it disabled using the cookies. How would I add that function to the existing code? Thanks!

Comment: Do the same thing you're already doing for the `checked` property but apply it to the `disabled` property. All of the code is already there, just tweak it

Comment: @Mike C To keep it checked, I do this: <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="myCheck" onclick="set_check();"> But I am not sure what to do to keep it disabled. And I am not sure what to add to the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

```
onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('myCheck').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    e.target.disabled = (getCookie('myCheck') == 1);
  }
  document.getElementById('myCheck').checked = (getCookie('myCheck') == 1);
}
```

Comment: Ritesh this disables but only after the page is reloaded. Is there a way to disable right after the check is set?

Comment: Does the checkbox have human interaction as well? I thought you want to check/uncheck it based on cookie value only.